# How to export display from an vagrant Linux box to MacOS host?

Tags: macos, vagrant, centos7, x11

I've got a Mac OS with Catalina installed. In this MAC Os host, I run a VirtualBox centos linux box (installed with Vagrant). In the Centos virtual Box I want to launch app like (google-chrome or any x application) with the display exported to the MacOS host.

I've set the X11Forwarding yes in /etc/ssh/sshd_config (in MacOS Box AND in the Centos BOX).
On MacOS i've installed and running XQuartz, which is working well (I can start xterm from MacOs XQuartz configuration for example).

I ssh from MacOs into my Centos box with -X. So X11 port forwarding must be ok.

When I start any graphical application from Centos (google-chrome for example), I always have this message :

> (google-chrome:26817): Gtk-WARNING **: 17:49:49.940: cannot open display:

I've tried some export DISPLAY configuration but without success : always cannot open dispay

Any help would be greatly appreciated because I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my problem. It is just a matter of NIC interface used when starting VM through Vagrant. If I use the Wifi NIC -> KO. If I use the Ethernet NIC it is ok.